# Pandas Python Grouped data boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I'm trying to group time stamped data by hour, then fill NaNs for hour with zero then create a boxplot for each hour. I tried the code below:

`df.groupby(df.index.hour).fillna(0).boxplot()`

and got this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Any help with how to create a boxplot with the zeros included in place of NaNs?

Sample df is below. endDate is the index:

```
endDate sourceName  sourceVersion   device  type    unit    creationDate    startDate   value
9/24/2014 15:07 iPhone          StepCount   count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:07 47
9/24/2014 15:12 iPhone          StepCount   count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:12 518
9/24/2014 15:17 iPhone          StepCount   count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:17 608
9/24/2014 15:22 iPhone          StepCount   count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:22 541
9/24/2014 15:27 iPhone          StepCount   count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:27 823
```

Comment: try to stick to these standards when asking a  question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for the link. I updated the post, is that better or do I still need to make more changes or add more info? Thanks!